# How to read a specific word in text file and copy it into excel?

Tags: c#, excel, text-files

I have a text file as shown below

Name:xxxx   Address:xxxxx   Contact No: xxx NIC No: xxxx

in a single string.
I want to read the text file and extract only the name address contact number and NIC no using c# into an excel sheet.

I was able to read the whole string and save it into an excel sheet.

Comment: So your Name, Address and other fields are separated with tab or single space?

Comment: By 'single string' do you mean 'single line'? Is each record on a separate line? Otherwise is Name - Address - Contact No - NIC *order* and/or *presence* guaranteed?

Comment: yes yes its in single line

Comment: Hi Hans, I may a bit late, but can u tell me how did u read each line from the text file and copy it into the excel file? I actually need to do exactly what u posted here with a very few changes, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you already know how to read a textfile and how to write to Excel. Remains the problem of how to split the line into separate values.

IF all those lines have the same field labels and field order, then you could use a regex to parse the line:

```
string line = "Name: xx xx Address:yyy yyYY Contact No: 1234 NIC No: xXxX";

var regex = new Regex(@"Name:\s*(.*)\s*Address:\s*(.*)\s*Contact No:\s*(.*)\s*NIC No:\s*(.*)\s*");

var match = regex.Match(line);
if (match.Success)
{
    var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var address = match.Groups[2].Value;
    var contactNo = match.Groups[3].Value;
    var nic = match.Groups[4].Value;

    // TODO write these fields to Excel
}
```

This regex uses the field labels ("Name:", "Address:", etc) to find the values you need. The `\s*` parts mean that any whitespace around the values is ignored. The `(.*)` parts capture values into Groups in the match class, counting from 1.

Comment: this only gives me one record!

Comment: @devin - you need to repeat it for every line in every file that's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If your Name, Address Contact No etc. fields are separated using a tab delimiter (\t) then you can split the string using tab delimiter like this:

```
string.Split('\t');
```

Instead of `\t` you can use whatever delimiter is there is the text file.

If you have a space then you might have a problem because the fields and field values may have spaces in between.

Comment: some of them are separated using a space.

Comment: some of them are separated using tab and it contains like 700 text files in one folder that is the problem! i was able to read the whole file and copied it into a excel file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you have only one record in each file.
Let's suppose your data in a single file is:

> Name:N1 Address:A1 W. X, Y - Z Contact No: C1 NIC No: I1 Name:N2 Address:A2 W. X, Y - Z Contact No: C2 NIC No: I2

So there are 2 records on a single line (but there could be more)

> Name:N1 Address:A1 W. X, Y - Z Contact No: C1 NIC No: I1
>
> Name:N2 Address:A2 W. X, Y - Z Contact No: C2 NIC No: I2

I don't think splitting by white spaces is practical because fields like name and address may contain spaces. Ideally colon symbol (`:`) is used only as delimiter between keys and values and it's not used in any value. Otherwise the solution gets more complicated.

Also, I assume that the order of keys is guaranteed to be as in the example above:

```
Name
Address
Contact No
NIC No
```

Use a list of custom objects or a `DataTable` to hold your structured data.
In this example I will use `DataTable`:

```
var separators = new char[] { ':' };

var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
data.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
data.Columns.Add("ContractNo", typeof(string));
data.Columns.Add("NICNo", typeof(string));
```

For each file with records, open the file, read the file content and "process" it:

```
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
   //read file content
   string fileContent = ...;

   string[] tokens = fileContent.Split(separators);
   //we skip first token. It will always be 'Name'.

   for(int i = 0; i < (tokens - 1) / 4; i++)
   {
      var record = data.NewRow();
      string token = tokens[i * 4 + 1]; 
      record["Name"] = token.Substring(0, token.Lenght - 7).Trim(); // Remove 'Address' from end and trim spaces

      token = tokens[i * 4 + 2];
      record["Address"] = token.Substring(0, token.Length - 10).Trim(); //Remove 'Contact No' from end and trim spaces

      token = tokens[i * 4 + 3];
      record["ContractNo"] = token.Substring(0, token.Length - 6).Trim(); //Remove 'NIC No' from end and trim spaces

      token = tokens[i * 4 + 4];
      if (token.EndsWith('Name')) //if there are multiple records
         token = token.Substring(0, token.Length - 4);
      record["NICNo"] = token.Trim();

      data.Rows.Add(record);
   } 

}
```

This will also work if each file contains only one record.
Now that you have the structured data in a data table it should be easy to insert them in excel worksheet.

Comment: I tried the one with regx but i only managed to get one record!

Comment: The elegant solution provided by Hans can be slightly changed to capture multiple matches (using `Regex.Matches`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);

        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Address");
        dt.Columns.Add("Contact No");
        dt.Columns.Add("NIC");

        foreach (string txtName in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\unityapp\tab02", "*.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName);

            //string line = "Name: Address: Contact No:  NIC No:";

            string[] token1 = sr.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "Name: ", "Address: ", "Contact No: ", "NIC No:" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

dt.Rows.Add(token1[1], token1[2], token1[3], token1[4]);


        }

       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application x = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     //  Workbook wb = x.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Book1.xlsx");
       Workbook wb = x.Workbooks.Add();

       Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook();
    // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();


        sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
        sheet.Cells[1, 1].Interior.ColorIndex = 10;
        sheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Address";
        sheet.Cells[1, 2].Interior.ColorIndex = 20;
        sheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Contact No";
        sheet.Cells[1, 3].Interior.ColorIndex = 30;
        sheet.Cells[1, 4] = "NIC";
        sheet.Cells[1, 4].Interior.ColorIndex = 40;


        int rowCounter = 2;
        int columnCounter = 1;


        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            sheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = dr["Name"].ToString();
            columnCounter += 1;
            sheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = dr["Address"].ToString();
            columnCounter += 1;
            sheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = dr["Contact No"].ToString();
            columnCounter += 1;
            sheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = dr["NIC"].ToString();
            rowCounter += 1;
            columnCounter = 1;

        }

        wb.SaveAs(@"D:\Unity.xlsx");
        wb.Close();
        x.Quit();

        Process.Start(@"D:\Unity.xlsx");
    }

}
```

}